# Visual Basic.NET "The output char buffer is too small to contain the decoded characters, encoding 'Unicode (UTF-8)' fallback 'System

Tags: binaryreader

I am trying to read a binary file in which i have been appending data using a `BinaryWriter` object. I keep getting this error:

> "The output char buffer is too small to contain the decoded
>   characters, encoding 'Unicode (UTF-8)' fallback
>   'System.Text.DecoderReplacementFallback'."

My file has characters like `|` which i suspect are the problem but I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 4):

The most probable reason is that your file contains some binary data, that does not represent valid UTF-8 codepoint, at the place from which you are trying to read UTF-8 character.

This can happen if your read algorithm lose "synchronization" with your write algorithm and tries to read character from the wrong place, where something else (not a character) was written.